# Angular 10 subscribe is failing to post with error code OK(and no other errors shown)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am new to angular 10 and I am trying to make an http post to a PHP file as shown below

```
 this.http.post(`${environment.server}/path/file.php`, {param1, param2})
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
      },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
      this.error = error;
    });
```

The file is successfully called and returns the following JSON as displayed in the console response

[image]

```
{"Email":null,"school_year":2021,"academic_year":"2021"}
```

When I make the request I am immediately taken to the error state and all the console log is showing below only prints "OK"

```
console.log(error);
```

The two questions are the following

1. Why am getting to the error when the file is successfully returning JSON
2. Is there a way to get a more helpful error message than just OK

Comment: Why are you sending console.log as the data payload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set the content type to `application/json`

You would be better off if you used a rest API rather than using php files. .NET Core or Node.JS would give you a better development experience.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your back-end `PHP` send the response with `status code 400`. It should be revised to `200` to get the data in `response`. When Status code is in Error range like `400`, `401`, `403` ... `http Response` will resolved in `error` or `catch` part.

In addition if you want just get data, it's better to use `GET` instead of `POST`.

Comment: I edited my post,
I am getting status code 200
I appreciate the explanation on how it resolved to error